# How to get the last post from wp multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, foreach, blogs

i have to get the last post from my multisite network on wordpress.
For now i use this code for display the last updated post after a cycle on each blog_id:

```
<?php

$blogs = get_last_updated(' ', 0, 1);
foreach ($blogs AS $blog);
    switch_to_blog($blog["blog_id"]);
        $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=1&orderby=date');
        foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
```

But if i want to get the last post and not the last post updated how can i do? Because if i change and refresh a post i get the post like the last on main page. But this is not the real last post.

Comment: WordPress questions about programming and administration are best asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Remove the ordertby=date  and add the arg 'order'=> 'ASC' or 'DESC'

Comment: But the problem i think is the command get_last_updated because it doesn't bring the real last post, but the last modified post.